# Sorting a dynamic table using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using javaScript I am populating the table headers and table data dynamically. I would like to sort the rows of table based on which header cell is clicked.

NOTE: Main requirement is I don't want to use any jQuery plugins such as tablesorter, jqGrid etc.,

Comment: http://www.roseindia.net/javascript/javascriptexamples/javascript-sort-table.shtml might help

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I want to use jQuery to sort the table but not any of jQuery plugins.

Comment: You should look at jQuery plugins and write code based off of them. Reading their sources should instruct you how to do this correctly.

Comment: That's a lot of code to write if you do not want to use any plugin. Is this homework? Take a look at jqgrid or datatables code. you need to take care of typed sort also: Alphabetic, Numeric, Date etc.

Comment: Java and JavaScript are different languages. Please be careful in selecting tags.

Comment: I never understood this logic. Once you start writing this code, you're essentially just building a custom plugin. Why make it so difficult?

Answer (score 0):

One of the ideas is,

***onlick*** of the table header(have to write this code in the ajax server code) call the jquery ajax function which gets the table content dynamically.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function getTableData(sort_field, sort_by) { // sort_field: id, date, name.. & sort_by: ascending or descending
        // do call ajax function for getting the data. 
        // Pass the sort_field and sort_by value as sort field name and 
        // do the server code accordingly.
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
<tr>
<th onclick="getTableData('date','asc');">Date</th>
</tr>
</table>
```